# Programmatically checking valid combinations of metrics and dimensions for GA

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is there any programmatic way for checking valid combinations of metrics and dimensions?
Analytics query explorer seem to be detecting it.  Query explorer code is @ https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/tree/master/src/javascript/query-explorer

But by dev. says he can't find a way to it. Thanks in advance.

My API errors have gone to 20% in console with wrong queries. Also google will not allow to Extend API calls with this much errors.

Comment: Did you find the solution to validating metrics and dimension combinations?

Comment: @PiyushKhera nope

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768915/google-analytics-metadata-api-allowed-dimensions-metrics-combinations