# Google Analytics Metadata API: Allowed Dimensions/Metrics Combinations

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

The Metadata API doesn't have an attribute or specific mapping to allowed dimensions/metrics combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a question or a statement but you are correct the [Google Analytics metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) returns a list of dimensions and metrics that can be used in the [Google Analytics Core reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/).

At this time there is no API that will tell you which dimensions and metrics are valid combinations.  the only way to do that is to check the [dimensions and metrics reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) manually or run the request and see what happens.

I have discussed it with the API team over the last several years its on there list but I don't think it has a very high priority for them.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not there after 4 years. But they claim Metadata API was used to create the dimensions and metrics explorer.